# concatenate two values ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to map one value to other, following is my code
what im trying to do is call one api and get that values and pass to another api and map both values in the end, i get the values from both apis but failing to concatenate. how to solve this?

```
response = conn.get("/api/vhosts")
      statistics = JSON.parse(response.body)
      statistics.each do |vhosts|
       # puts "vhostname: #{vhosts["name"]}"
          response1 = conn.get("/api/aliveness-test/#{vhosts["name"]}")
          statistics1 = JSON.parse(response1.body)
          puts "#{vhosts["name"]} " + statistics1.fetch('status', :unknown)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Which is the error or what is the problem right now? Help us to help you

Comment: error :  no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
@Ursus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferably, concatenate string using `<<` is a little more [faster and performatic](http://greyblake.com/blog/2012/09/02/ruby-perfomance-tricks/):

```
 puts "#{vhosts["name"]} " << statistics1.fetch('status', :unknown).to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling that you are trying to concatenate a string and a symbol. So, one of the two parts is a symbol, not a string. You have some options.

```
puts "#{vhosts["name"]} #{statistics1.fetch('status', :unknown)}"
```

or

```
puts "#{vhosts["name"]} " + statistics1.fetch('status', :unknown).to_s
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir. Good luck with the ring :)